# checkbox checked persistent with local Storage in angular js

Tags: javascript, angularjs, checkbox, local-storage

I want to make "checkbox are persistent" with localStorage when I reload my view are not lost.

The values that I'm saving the checked in localStorage with the help of ngStorage.

This is my code and demo https://jsfiddle.net/alx_lopz/bhgmw7ey/

```
<div ng-app="myApp">
    <div ng-controller="favCtrl">

        <div ng-repeat="chip in colores" >
            <input type="checkbox" name="{{chip.codigo}}" id="{{chip.codigo}}" ng-model="chip.checked" ng-change="chipsColores()"  ng-click="$storage.a = fav">
            <label>{{chip.codigo}}</label>
        </div>

        <div ng-repeat="favorite in $storage.a">
            localStorage: {{favorite.codigo}}
        </div>

    </div>
</div>
```

my controller:

```
(function(){

    angular.module('myApp',['ngStorage'])

    .controller('favCtrl',[ '$scope', '$filter', '$localStorage', function ( $scope, $filter, $localStorage) {
        $scope.colores = [
            {'nombre':'blue', 'codigo':'1111'},
            {'nombre':'green', 'codigo':'2222'},
            {'nombre':'red', 'codigo':'3333'}

        ];

        $scope.chipsColores = function () {
            $scope.fav = $filter('filter')($scope.colores, {checked: true});
        }
        $scope.$storage =  $localStorage.$default({
        });


    }])
})();
```

Please I need your help in my demo! Thanks...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you want to do is probably to just store the map of the checked values - i.e. control ids (color ids) to it's checked state. So the key is to just update the map on `ng-click`:

```
$storage.a[chip.codigo] = chip.checked
```

and then use `ng-checked="$storage.a[chip.codigo]"`. Please remember that it is also important to initialise map object first:

```
$localStorage.$default({
  a: {}  
});
```

here is updated fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/ciekawy/az2ehwon/

Comment: Thanks for the explanation and demonstration. That's what I wanted, but I have a problem when I uncheck the checkbox value does not disappear from view. How can I do that?.

Sorry, I'm Beginning javascript and angular

Comment: You mean the fact that after unchecking i.e. `111` there is `localStorage: 1111: false` at the bottom? actually this is how you should use this. If for this diagnostic view you want to skip unchecked items, then it's enough to add `ng-if="value"` along with `ng-repeat`.

Answer (score 0):

You can just save the data like this:

```
$scope.$storage = $localStorage.$default({
    someKey1: value1,
    someKey2: value2
});
```

Then the `$scope.$storage` object will be created with the default value. And saved into localStorage if some valued changed. You just need to bind the `$storage` object in view with some elements.